# Finding & unpacking CIDR blocks inside list of tuples

Tags: python, python-ipaddress

I'm working with an exported list of file repositories and their corresponding lists of IP addresses from which they are allowed to accept uploads.  It is a large list of tuples and it is formatted like so:

```
[('Repo1', '192.168.90.0/24','192.168.1.10'), ('Repo2', '10.3.1.0/24'), ('Repo3', '10.2.11.0/24','10.12.127.0/24','10.57.3.0/24')]
```

I imported the ipaddress module and used the `ip_network` function:

```
sample = ipaddress.ip_network('10.2.11.0/24')

for i in sample:
    print(i)
```

This is what I want but I am unsure of how to run it on nested elements in my big list of tuples.

How can I identify every element that has a CIDR block (not every one does and some have multiple), run this function to unpack it, and put the element back together?

End goal being to save it to a file like csv.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. When can apply a function on a single item, you can apply it to each element of a list consisting of several items. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: I tried my best, this is a little tough to explain

Comment: The quoting doesn't looks correct in the `Repo3` tuple. Please post the actual value.

Comment: It seems like you just need nested loops. Iterate over the list of tuples in the outer loop, then iterate over the CIDR blocks in the inner loop.